# slow powershell/powerCLI performance when invoked from Java

Tags: java, performance, powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a powerCLI script that queries the VmWare hosts for information. I'm able to run the script from java by doing this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive -file \"" + scriptPath + "\"";
Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
```

I've verified that the script works the same when ran from Powershell command line or through Java. However, I repeatedly noticed that when invoked from Java, it takes about 45 secs to finish (compared to about 20 secs from the command line).

Any idea why the difference in performance?
Thank you

Edit: For clarification: In my powerCLI script, I capture the start and finish time and then print out the duration from within the script. The 45 vs 20 seconds mentioned was observed from the Powershell script printout. So this time would not include the overhead associated with calling and returning.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a lot more going on there, you have to get an instance of the runtime, run powershell passing it a script then call back into the runtime to say that the program has finished running.

Its just the Java overhead.

Comment: That's true, but this is the reason why I'm asking: In my powerCLI script, I capture the start and finish time and then print out the duration from within the script. The 45 vs 20 seconds mentioned was observed from the Powershell script printout. So this time would not include the overhead associated with calling and returning.

Comment: hmmm interesting, i have no clue then.

Answer (score 0):

How do you load the PowerCLI snapins ? There are some optimizations in Windows InternetSettings that validate snapin origin. You can turn this off. I'm not sure how Java (or at all) takes into consideration these settings. Read this article http://goo.gl/PGUqa and try the explanations there.